# Angular Material Datepicker bug in Firefox

Tags: angular, firefox, angular-material, angular-material-datetimepicker

I'm not sure if anyone has witnessed this... but using Angular material and trying to use the datepicker. A couple of dates combine the day and year to a weird fraction. This seems to happen only on firefox and I can't replicate it on chrome or Edge. Most times the date picker works fine... but when I select the first of the month, it shows a fraction (mostly happening in firefox).

```
  <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class='datepicker regulartext'>
                        <mat-label>{{ label }}</mat-label>
                        <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" [formControlName]="name" [min]="todayDate">
                        <mat-hint>Format: MM/DD/YYYY</mat-hint>
                        <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                        <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
                    </mat-form-field>
```

And this is what happens in firefox...
[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Please reproduce the issue on the stackblitz. Opening the [examples on the official docs](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/examples) in Firefox 121.0.1 I can't seem to reproduce the issue, so odds are it's something else in your code.

Comment: I suspect appearance="outline" might create this

Comment: I did some digging and it wasn't a firefox issue like ya'all pointed out. I was inheriting the font property from the parent element and it was causing this to happen. The weird thing is ... it was only happening on Firefox lol. But thanks for the pointers.

Comment: appearance = "outline" with an inherit font property was causing this =/